# How to create custom dependency software for project setup?

Tags: c#, .net, setup-project, packaging

I recently build a project with C# .Net 4.5 and now I need to creating setup package for release but before install project must have installed SQL Server Express 2012 LocalDB in destination system.
I tried to use Setup Factory for create dependency module but it has just own software for example: .Net 3.5 4 4.5 and so on.
what should I do for install a software for example `SQL Server Express 2012 LocalDB` before installed my project?

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using, and does it support VS setup projects? And have you seen this? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2014/04/17/visual-studio-installer-projects-extension.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I've already done your suggestion, I put `#SUFDIR#\Dependencies\sqlLocalDB\SqlLocaLDB.MSI` to `name -> properties->files` but it didn't works.

But [Advanced Installer 11.7.1](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/)
solved my problem, I recommended to use this software for create setup.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem but Solved.
in setup factory go
dependencies->Advanced->create new module
type name and click ok.

> Right click on new module name -> properties->files
>
> click to new (sqaure with plus mark)->[...]

add your custom dependencies like SQL Server Express 2012 LocalDB and other